Oven and cooktop instalation
I am installing an oven and cooktop. I've made a drawing below to make it easier to illustrate and I'll provide photos at the end. For context I live in Germany.

What connections would you advise here? I am lost with the brown wire.

Link to the photos https://imgur.com/a/H4IOXuq

Your drawings have you shorting 2 of your phases together. I'd advise that you stop what you're doing and get a competent electrician.

Can you share the installation instructions?

Cooktop appears to be from Ikea, but is not available in the US: https://www.ikea.com/gb/en/p/vilsta-induction-hob-ikea-300-black-90557725/
